# Purpose of properties in ISaveAction

Tags: wffm

I'm starting to explore building a custom save action in WFFM using an implementation of `ISaveAction`.  I know the bulk of my work will be in the `Execute()` method, but I'd like to know what all of the other properties do. All of the examples that I've found use either a default implementation of the getters and setters (for `ActionID` and `UniqueKey`) or else a hard coded response (`ActionType.Save` for `ActionType` or `ActionState.Enabled` for `QueryState()`).  I can't seem to locate any documentation, discussion of what they all do, or any other indication of what the "right" implementation are.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore's documentation on the `ISaveAction` interface is a bit limited, and I can certainly appreciate wanting to know more about it before trying to implement it, yourself. Below, I have provided a detailed breakdown of each of the properties that you mentioned from the `ISaveAction` interface.

It should be noted that all of the mentioned properties are actually defined on the `Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.IAction` interface, which is inherited by the `Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.ISaveAction` interface.

For reference, I primarily used Web Forms for Marketers 8.2 rev. 161129 during my analysis. I looked through a couple of other versions as well, but did not see any significant differences.

#### `ActionID`

The `ActionID` property is pretty straight-forward: it is the ID of the Save Action item, in Sitecore. It should have a default getter and setter, as Sitecore's internal logic is responsible for setting the property's value. For a Save Action, this happens in the `DefaultImplActionExecutor.ExecuteSaving` method.

#### `UniqueKey`

The `UniqueKey` property of the `ISaveAction` (inherited from `IAction`) maps to the `Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.IActionDefinition.UniqueKey` property, which is a unique string that helps to identify the instance definition of the action on a form. Like the `ActionID`, the `UniqueKey` should have a default getter and setter, as Sitecore's internal logic, again in the `DefaultImplActionExecutor.ExecuteSaving` method, is responsible for setting the property's value.

The purpose of the `UniqueKey` property is a bit trickier to wrap your mind around, but is a bit easier when thinking about an example. Consider that you have an Email Save Action. There is an item for that Save Action and that item has an ID that maps to `ActionID`. The default settings for the action are stored on the action item itself, but now assume that you add the action to the form *Foo*. At this point, you need to update the instance-specific settings for the action (e.g. To, From, Message Body, Subject, etc.) and save the settings such that Sitecore knows that the settings you updated belong only to the instance of the Email Save Action that is on the *Foo* form. Sitecore doesn't change the template, so instead it saves the data as an `ActionDefinition` (which I believe is stored as XML). The `UniqueKey` on the save action then helps to identify the instance of the save action that your class represents.

#### `ActionType`

It makes sense that the `ActionType` property would be hard-coded for a save action. The `ActionType` property is typed to the following enum:

```
namespace Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions
{
  public enum ActionType
  {
    Undefined,
    Check,
    Save,
    System,
    Custom,
  }
}
```

Since you are implementing a *Save* Action, your `ActionType` is always going to be `ActionType.Save`. As for the other values, it appears that Sitecore does not currently make use of them. They are likely there for future development purposes that have not yet been made clear.

You can always file a support ticket to inquire about additional information and more clarity regarding the purpose that the other values will serve, but I would expect that Sitecore will give you the same response as I did.

#### `QueryState`

Similar to the `ActionType` property, the `QueryState` also makes sense to be hard-coded for a Save Action. The `QueryState` property is typed to the following enum:

```
namespace Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions
{
  public enum ActionState
  {
    Undefined,
    Disabled,
    Enabled,
    SingleCall,
    Hidden,
    DisabledSingleCall,
  }
}
```

As with the `ActionType` enum, Sitecore appears to only use the `ActionState.Enabled` value at present, and the other values are likely included for future feature development. Based on the use of the `ActionState.Enabled` value and the naming of the other values, I think it is safe to infer that the purpose of these options is to allow the developer to control the frequency in which an action can be called. A `Disabled` action would never be called, `Enabled` would always be called, and `SingleCall` would be called once and would then change to a `DisabledSingleCall` so that it won't be called again. I'm not sure what `Hidden` would do, but as with the `ActionType` enum, we won't know more until Sitecore releases updates that make use of these properties.

Again, you can file a Support ticket with Sitecore to inquire about additional information on this property, but I would expect them to give you the same answer as I did.